# Updating data to sql via python - ProgrammingError: ('HY000', 'Attempt to use a closed connection.')

Tags: python, sql

Can anyone help me fix this code? I am new to Python.

What I'm trying to do is extract Python web scraped data into SQL, but I got this error:

> DatabaseError: ('21S01', '[21S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.')

and

> TypeError: 'DatabaseError' object is not subscriptable.

After I have included `conn.commit()` at the end of the code. Now I get this error.

> ProgrammingError: ('HY000', 'Attempt to use a closed connection.')

This is the code - can you please help me to identify the error?

```
import pypyodbc as odbc # pip install pypyodbc
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\sahan\Desktop\Empdata.xlsx')

columns = ['nameX', 'id', 'mark', 'department'] 
        
df_data = df[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()

DRIVER = 'SQL Server'
SERVER_NAME = 'LAPTOP-DIVPVC2Q\SQLEXPRESS'
DATABASE_NAME = 'CSE'

def connection_string(driver, server_name, database_name):
    conn_string = f"""
        DRIVER={{{driver}}};
        SERVER={server_name};
        DATABASE={database_name};
        Trust_Connection=yes;        
    """
    return conn_string


try:
    conn = odbc.connect(connection_string(DRIVER, SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME))
except odbc.DatabaseError as e:
    print('Database Error:')    
    print(str(e.value[1]))
except odbc.Error as e:
    print('Connection Error:')
    print(str(e.value[1]))



sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO emp_data
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, GETDATE())
'''

try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
    cursor.commit();    
except Exception as e:
    cursor.rollback()
    print(str(e[1]))
finally:
    print('Task is complete.')
    cursor.close()
    conn.commit ()
    conn.close()
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

When you use "insert into", you must provide a value for every column in the table.  It looks like you are dropping all but four columns in the input file.  If these are not the only fields in the table you are inserting into, you will get the table definition error.